# Quick actions & Salesforce1 Actions missing from Global Publisher Layout pallet.

Tags: global-actions

When I navigate to: Create | Global Actions | Publisher Layouts, there should be 2 categories in the pallet: Quick Actions and Salesforce1 Actions. However, I only have 'Actions'. I have created a new Global Publisher layout, edited the existing, et al. No luck. Not sure what/why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is only available in Summer '15 organizations. (look for the ice cream truck). If you are still not seeing this please log a support case as these should be automatically on without any admin setup.